Is there a way to use the picked image without running flutter clean?
Problem Statement
I'm trying to use an image in a profile, by picking it using the file_picker package,
the pubspec.yaml path are correct and the path provided to the AssetImage as well.
But the after picking the image, an 'Asset not found' exception is thrown.
The only way to use the image was by running 'flutter clean'.
Is there a mechanism to workaround that without explicitly running 'flutter clean'?
The process of using the image is:
Picking the image file:
final file = await pickFile();

/*
Future<File?> pickFile() async {
  final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: false);
  if (result != null) {
    return File(result.files.single.path!);
  }
  return null;
}
*/

Pushing the image file path after copying it to the assets directory:
// This name generation step is temporary.
String uniqueName = '${DateTime.now().toString()
                     .replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[^0-9]'))}'
             '.' + file.path.split('.').last.toString()';

// Don't worry about file extension validation, it's not implemented yet.

final copiedFile = file.copySync('assets/$uniqueName');

ref.read(pickedImagePathProvider.notifier).update((_) => movedFile.path);

/*
final pickedFilePathProvider = StateProvider<String>((ref) {
  return 'assets/1.png'; 
});

note/ 1.png is a default image that is already exist in the assets directory.
*/

Using the image by the path provided:
final imagePath = ref.watch(pickedFilePathProvider);
    
Image(image: AssetImage(imagePath)),


whats the purpose of file.copySync('assets/$uniqueName');? assets folder is read-only so what actually do you want to achieve?

keeping the picked images in a relative location?
you mean that the write is happening indirectly (after flutter clean..)?
So what do you think is the best approach?

Copy your file to a "normal" folder where you have the rights to do that

inside the project directory? and if that's the case, could I access it? it would be the same as the assets directory because it will be added to the pubspec, ain't it?

no, it will not be added to the pubspec.yaml

You can't save the files to the asset folder in your app. That is a read-only file. You should get the save file path using path_provider package to save the files.
final Directory appDocumentsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final copiedFile = file.copySync('appDocumentsDir.path/$uniqueName');

